# Видимость приватных полей (С++)

Tags: c++, классы

Можно ли внутри класса обращаться к приватным полям обьекта того же класса?

Comment: Только внутри него и можно :) Ну, еще и в друзьях...

Comment: Что значит внутри класса? Внутри объекта? К полям того же объекта? К полям другого объекта? Пример бы, а то не очень понятно о чём вы. Может Вы внутри статического метода пытаетесь получить доступ к приватным полям не статическим, хотя объекта никакого нет

Answer (score 2):

Можно, также можно и с дружествених классов, в этом и смысл private полей.

```
class a
{
private:
int b = 10;
public:
int c = b;
}
```

Данный пример полностю рабочий, поскольку переменная с в одном классе с переменной b;

Comment: Это не то, о чем вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Функции-члены класса имеют доступ к приватным членам других экземпляров того же класса, а не только к объекту, обозначенному как `this`. Если бы такого доступа не было, то нельзя было бы реализовать пользовательские операторы копирования/перемещения или соответствующие им конструкторы. Пример:

```
class A {
   int i;
   void f(A& other) { other.i = i; } // доступ к члену i другого объекта того же класса
};
```